# Not expanding glob with matlab -r

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to evaluate a MATLAB expression on the command line. I write something like

```
$ matlab -nojvm -r "disp(1 + 2); exit"
```

This prints some startup boilerplate, then 3, then brings me back to the shell. The problem is that if there's a `*` in the expression, it looks like MATLAB always expands it -- if I write `1 * 2` instead of `1 + 2`, I get an `Unexpected MATLAB expression` error because the `*` is replaced with a space separated list of the files in the current directory.

I've tried escaping with backslashes somehow, or wrapping the expression in an `eval` but the `*` is even expanded inside strings. I'm pretty sure this is MATLAB doing the expansion too, not the shell.

Is there a way around this? Or is evaluating arbitrary expressions just not an intended use of `matlab -r`? If so, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I guess you would need to put these expression in some function in m file, and execute this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like

```
echo -e "function my_entry_point\n$expr\nend" >> my_entry_point.m
matlab -nojvm -r "my_entry_point(); exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

The * is being expanded by the shell, not by matlab. If you enclose the statement in single quotes it will work

```
matlab -nojvm -r 'disp(1 * 2); exit'
```

For more complicated scripts, Marcin's idea of executing a file is probably a better approach though.

Comment: Have you tried this? The `*` is expanded even with single quotes, which is why I said I was pretty sure MATLAB was doing the expansion.